# context menu not working properly

Tags: android

please have a look at the code below...
i am creating a context menu and implementing the method `onContextItemSelected` but the problem is that when i press the reply item...the dialog on the delete case also appears and the activity also starts twice...means all the cases executes...the delete the reply and the forward case...what happens to be the problem please help

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
    case R.id.reply:
    {
            Intent i = new Intent();
             String s2 = (String) ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position))
                    .getString(2);
             i.putExtra("number", s2);
        //   Log.v("number", s2);
             i.setClass(this, CreateMessage.class);
            // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             startActivity(i);

    }   
        case R.id.delete:
        {

        final String s = (String) ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position))
                        .getString(1);

              dba = new DBAdapter(this);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //   Log.v("", "You Clicked " + s);             


                            dba.delete("messages", "id=?", new String[] { s });
                            populate();
                            dba.close();
                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
        }

        case R.id.forward:
        {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            String s3 = (String) ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position))
                    .getString(4);
        //  Log.v("message", s3);
            i.putExtra("message", s3);
            i.setClass(this, CreateMessage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
default:

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

and here is the error from the logcat that is displayed in the logcat...

```
03-30 09:13:28.439: E/WindowManager(2273): Activity sms.app.Displayer has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44eb95c8 that was originally added here
```

sms.app.Displayer is the class in which i am implementing the context menu..

and here is the code of the context menu file..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <item android:id="@+id/reply" android:title="Reply"></item><item
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:title="Forward">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/delete" android:title="Delete Message">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once check this code a minor change in your onContextItemSelected method::

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.reply:
            Intent i = new Intent();
            String s2 = (String) ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position))
                    .getString(2);
            i.putExtra("number", s2);
            //   Log.v("number", s2);
            i.setClass(this, CreateMessage.class);
            // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.delete:   

            final String s = (String) ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position))
                    .getString(1);

            dba = new DBAdapter(this);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //   Log.v("", "You Clicked " + s);             


                    dba.delete("messages", "id=?", new String[] { s });
                    populate();
                    dba.close();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        break;

        case R.id.forward:
            Intent i = new Intent();
            String s3 = (String) ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position))
                    .getString(4);
            //  Log.v("message", s3);
            i.putExtra("message", s3);
            i.setClass(this, CreateMessage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: yes thats right but the return true statement should be in the outer scope....not after the break statement

Answer (score 1):

add breaks after your case statements

Edit:
You fall thru to the following case blocks because you are missing the breaks. Either add breaks to you case statements (and handle the return value later) or directly add return true instead of the breaks.

Comment: the breaks gives an error that the method must return a boolean

Comment: then add return true instead of the breaks

Comment: if you add returns all cases are executed? or do you refer to the leaked decor view? this should be unrelated to the fall thru problem, but i'll have another look.

Comment: looks like some window, popup or dialog has not been dismissed before starting the new activity. are you displaying a dialog from which the context menu is opened?

Comment: what is this leaked decor view...?

Comment: after adding return the error is not shown in the logcat...both the error solved

Comment: ah, ok, so this fixed the leaked window thing as well right? just saw that the delete case would show a dialog and then you would fall thru to forward which would just open a new activity without dismissing the dialog of course, resulting in the leaked window. You should be fine then with the proper returns in there, right?

Comment: yes when i added the return statements the whole thing works fine...:))))